# Real User Monitoring for a C# Desktop App

Tags: c#, datadog

I am looking a viable approach to record the usage / performance of various parts of a C# desktop application. I see strong parallels with the web focused [Real User Monitoring](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/) technique and have access to Datadog to process my data.

Is RUM outside the web a viable approach? I believe I will have to implement the equivalent of the JS Datadog SDK if I want to go down this road, is there a way to do this out of the box?

I want to be able to track user usage for certain function calls and capturing exceptions seem sensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some event model disconnects between the desktop and web but RUM can be used with Android and iPhone apps as well. I implemented this using the json-schema files in the Android SDK and a bit of trial and error on how I wanted to map function calls into the RUM event model.